# InputEvent.getTargetRanges() always empty?

Tags: javascript, inputevent

I have a Div in my page that is set up as contenteditable=true, e.g.

```
<DIV contenteditable=true id="editor">Test</DIV>
```

I've got a simple function that dumps out event info whenever a change is made in the div:

```
document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    console.log("input event fired:",e)
    console.log("data:",e.data)
    console.log("dataTransfer:",e.dataTransfer)
    console.log("inputType:",e.inputType)
    console.log("isComposing:",e.isComposing)
    console.log("target ranges => ", e.getTargetRanges())
}, false);
```

The goal is to use the input event to construct a log of changes made to the div that can be replayed later.  For performance reasons, it is not desirable to try to do some diff comparing the div to its previous value.  Instead, the expectation is that the input event should provide the information about exactly what change in a compact manner.

Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/getTargetRanges),

> The getTargetRanges() property of the InputEvent interface returns an
>   array of static ranges that will be affected by a change to the DOM if
>   the input event is not canceled.

This function is supposed to return an array of StaticRange objects.

But whenever I see the input event fired, this function always returns an empty array.  As a result, insufficient information is available to determine what the change what.  For instance, if I type "x" I see `e.data` equals `"x"`, and `inputType` equals `"insertText"` so I know that "x" has been inserted *somewhere*, but `e.getTargetRanges()` returns an empty array, so I have no idea *where* it was inserted.

(This is on Chrome 77, and according to the chart this feature has been implemented in Chrome since version 60).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the ranges when using the `beforeinput` event. However, be aware of its [limited compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event#Browser_compatibility).

```js
document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("beforeinput", function(e) {
    if (e.data)
      console.log("data:",e.data);
    if (e.dataTransfer)
     console.log("dataTransfer data:", e.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
    const targetRanges = e.getTargetRanges();
    if (targetRanges && targetRanges.length > 0)
      console.log("target ranges => ", { startOffset: targetRanges[0].startOffset, endOffset: targetRanges[0].endOffset });
}, false);
```

```html
<DIV contenteditable=true id="editor">Test</DIV>
```

Comment: Can you expand on how it's compatibility is limited, the link doesn't seem to give much. It shows Chrome Android as having support but when I make this function call I am also getting an empty array

Comment: @PeterSaxton Looking at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=beforeinput), it is not supported in IE, and it is disabled by default in Firefox. According to caniuse, it should work in Chrome Android, but I don't have any personal experience with it.

Comment: caniuse just lists implemented and not implemented in which case the function wouldn't exist. The function seems to be there but giving an incorrect value